# Getting "bad request" in .NET 6 while using the same method signature and call from .NET 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following method for editing database objects in my controller class

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("PutDelete/{UserLogin}")]
public async Task<bool> PutDelete(List<View> viewlist, string UserLogin)
{
    // some code
}
```

I call this method in the following way:

```
await Http.PutJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/api/View/putDelete/" + SessionValue_user, viewlist);
```

with `viewlist` being of type `List<View>`.

That worked pretty fine in .NET 5. The method itself accepted the list of objects and did its thing (set a delete flag for context).

Now when doing the same thing with .NET 6, I get a "Bad Request" and error code 400. Do you know what could be the reason for that?

The requestURI looked fine to me and I also looked at the serialized json data and did not notice anything different. It looked exactly the same in both versions.

This is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public class View
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        #nullable enable

        public DateTime? orderedfordatetimeutc { get; set; }

        public DateTime? creationdateutc { get; set; }

        public string? locationid { get; set; }

        public string? firstname {get; set;}

        public string? lastname {get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public string? fullname => firstname + ", " + lastname;
    }
}
```

and the json being sent looks like this:

```
"[
    {
        \"orderedfordatetimeutc\":\"2023-06-10T00:00:00\",
        \"creationdateutc\":\"2023-06-10T00:00:00\",
        \"locationid\":\"UEB\",
        \"lastname\":\"Smith\",
        \"firstname\":\"John\",
        \"fullname\":\"John, Smith\"
    }
]"
```

Comment: Can you include in your post:  1) The class "View".  2) The json being sent in the body of the request?

Comment: i updated my code and included a sample class and a sample json. This is roughly how it looks with my real class.

Comment: Have you looked into the body of the Bad Request response what it tells you?

Comment: @Comfortable_Onion ... Thanks for the additional info.  Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The complex content 'viewList' will be sent in the body of the request.  In .Net6 you need to tell the binder to get the value from the body of the request:

```
public async Task<bool> PutDelete(
    [FromBody] List<View> viewlist, 
    string UserLogin)
```

If you prefer (I do) you can also explicitly mark UserLogin as coming from the route:

```
public async Task<bool> PutDelete(
    [FromBody] List<View> viewList,
    [FromRoute] string UserLogin)
```

but that bit is not necessary.

**UPDATE**

Following you posting of the model class and Json, I can see that "id" is not populated in the Json.  From .NET6 non-nullable reference-type fields must be populated for the binder to accept the payload.

Either ensure "id" is populated or redeclare it as a nullable type:

```
string? id { get; set; }
```

You should also prevent the inclusion of fullname in the json as it's a derived property so there's no value in including it.

```
using System.Text.Json

[JsonIgnore]
[NotMapped]
public string? fullname => firstname + ", " + lastname;
```

Comment: hey, I just tried that but unfortunately nothing changed. I still get a "BadRequest" error code 400.

Comment: Hi @Comfortable_Onion Please try to use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage` and check if could provide more details.